# How can I decrease the number of conditionals in if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord.js

how are you? Could you please help me?

How can i transform this

```
if ((confirmar = ["NÃO", "NAO", "não", "nao", "Não", "Nao"]))
return message.channel.send(
"Ok, sem problemas, a sua compra foi cancelada."
);
```

in this

```
if ((confirmar = ["NÃO", "NAO"]))
return message.channel.send(
"Ok, sem problemas, a sua compra foi cancelada."
);
```

Comment: and `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`

Comment: Better not do `=` in that "condition", as now execution will always continue in the `if` block.

Comment: `if (["NÃO", "NAO"].includes(confirmar.toUpperCase()))`

Comment: You're right, the code returned an error state [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot)

Comment: thank you [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), with your answer i was able to solve the problem in my code